# Toggle effects on redirecting to another .html?

Tags: jquery

JQuery `.toggle()` method hides/shows objects with beautiful effects. On my website, I have a hyperlink to another webpage on my site. Is it possible to give effects on page redirection? Such as in the `.toggle()` method.

Comment: You want to hide an element when the user is directed to a page from another page?

Comment: For a better understanding of your goal, can you add source code?

Comment: How are you loading the pages? With a page refresh? Then it is difficult to do this. Otherwise you could load the pages via AJAX and show / hide the container you are puytting the content in.

Comment: I don't want to toggle anything. I meant that .toggle() has effects, like the object is fading away. I want to do exactly the same with page redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean something like "sliding" off your current page and then having the new page underneath.

I am unaware of any way to do that with a page redirection as the browser is effectively throwing out the old page and putting a new one in its place.

You could request the page using ajax and then replace the content on your current page with the one you requested. This could have nice effects added to it.